# Qt 5 QWebEngine page printToPdf C2668 ambiguous call to overloaded function

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015, qt5, qtwebengine

I have the next code:

```
page.printToPdf("test.pdf");
```

but when compile it using VS2015 I'm getting this error:

```
error: C2668: 'QWebEnginePage::printToPdf': ambiguous call to overloaded function
```

and can't understand why because from the documentation:

```
printToPdf(const QString &filePath, ...)
printToPdf(FunctorOrLambda resultCallback, ...)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because both `QString` and `QByteArray` have a `const char *str` constructor. So the compiler can't tell which function to call.

You use `QString` for your 1st interface, while the 2nd one uses `QByteArray`. looking at  [qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#printToPdf-1)

> The resultCallback must take a const reference to a QByteArray as parameter.

Thus, explicitly passing `QString` or `QByteArray` should solve the problem. For example,

```
QString str = "test.pdf";
page.printToPdf(str);
```